# Where can I find 'Emily', the matrix visualization tool?

Tags: visualization, sparse-matrices

While searching for a tool to visualize sparse matrices I discovered [this paper about 'emily'](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6d3a/2f8123f4a3dee047c21e7cd0a6ec5f135abf.pdf), a piece of software which has everything I need. However, I cannot find a place to download or purchase the thing.

The paper was published in 1994 and I'm really having a hard time finding any information beyond that which is told by the document. Does anybody happen to know something about the whereabouts of Emily?

**tl;dr** Where is Emily?

Comment: You could try contacting the authors of the paper you link to or this one https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.1137

Comment: Did that - no reply :(